# why isn't the listview showing the text that input by the user

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need your help.

I'm making a function for my app that has the user add something by pressing the add button, it will then navigate to an adding page and then from the adding page it will add a new listtile in the listview. But I don't know why the text that was input by the user cannot be shown. Can anyone help me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'storage for each listview.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'adding page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => Storage(),
      child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<Storage>(context, listen: false);
    final storageaccess = provider.storage;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('app'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: storageaccess.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(storageaccess[index].title),
                subtitle: Text(storageaccess[index].titlediary.toString()),
                onTap: () {},
                onLongPress: () {
                  //delete function here
                },
              );
            }),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => addpage()));
          }, //void add
          tooltip: 'add diary',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ) // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}



/// this one I did not do anything first this one for later today just make UI
class Things {
  String title;
  DateTime titlediary;

  Things({required this.title, required this.titlediary});
}

class addpage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _addpageState createState() => _addpageState();
}

class _addpageState extends State<addpage> {

  String title = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextEditingController titleController=TextEditingController(text: title);
    final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('enter page ',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
      ),
      body:Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: titleController,
              autofocus: true,
              validator: (title) {
                if (title!.length < 0) {
                  return 'enter a title ';
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'title',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  final accessthing = Things(
                    title: title,
                    titlediary: DateTime.now(),
                  );
                  final provideraccess = Provider.of<Storage>(context, listen: false);
                  provideraccess.add(accessthing);
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>MyHomePage()));
                }
              },
              child: Text('Save'),
            ),
          ],
        ),),);
  }
}

class Storage extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Things> storage = [
    Things(
      title: 'hard code one ',
      titlediary: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Things(
      title: 'hard code two ',
      titlediary: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Things(
      title: 'hard code two ',
      titlediary: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Things(
      title: 'hard code two ',
      titlediary: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];
  void add(Things variablethings) {
    storage.add(variablethings);
  } notifyListeners();
}
```

after the user clicks the addbutton, it will send them to an adding page, then after clicking save, the data will be saved into a storage page and then the provider will add the data provided by the user, but the text will not show on the listtile.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is happening because you are Navigating to HomePage again using,

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>MyHomePage()));
```

but this time it is not connected to your provider context.

[
In detail: As you have used `ChangeNotifierProvider()` in `MyApp` then connected the `MyHomePage()` there. But if you push again in Navigator, then fluter creates a separate instance of `MyHomePage()` widget. Which will not be connected to `ChangeNotifierProvider()` in `MyApp`
].

In place of this, use `Navigator.of(context).pop();`
And in onPressed() use this,

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
 --->     onPressed: () async {
 --->       await Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => addpage()));
 --->       setState((){});
          },
```